# VBA automatically changes upper to lower case letters

Tags: ms-access, vba

So my problem is that I want to type for example `Forms!Judge![name].SetFocus` but instead VBA automatically changes it to `Forms!judge![name].SetFocus` so the name of the form doesn't match. How do I override it?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

VBA will only automatically change the name if it finds something associated with that name.  Check all your DIM statements, and make sure your form name is correct.

Also, save yourself the headache later and NEVER use "reserved" words for field names.  You obviously have a field or textbox named "Name"; you should change that to JudgeName or JName or something OTHER than "Name".  Trust me, you'll thank me for that.

Comment: Some of the forms had the same name as tables - guess that's the case. Thanks for help